# How does one mount a file system (afs, cifs, or smb) at boot so that the mount is persistent. (mac 10.6.6)

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, boot, mount

I would like to have directories on several PCs available to other users of a macbook pro running 10.6.6.  Is this possible?  I was able to get this to work for nfs via the disk-utility.  I purchased Lingon from the App Store, but I cannot see how to do it with Lingon either.

Many thanks to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0):

AFS is a special case (unless you meant AFP); it's mounted by the AFS cache manager when it's launched.  Otherwise, per `man diskarbitrationd`:

> The file `/etc/fstab` is consulted for user-defined mount points, indexed
>   by filesystem, in the mount point determination for a filesystem.  Each
>   filesystem can be identified by its UUID or by its label, using the
>   constructs `UUID` or `LABEL`, respectively.  For example:
>
> ```
> UUID=DF000C7E-AE0C-3B15-B730-DFD2EF15CB91 /export ufs   ro
> UUID=FAB060E9-79F7-33FF-BE85-E1D3ABD3EDEA none    hfs   rw,noauto
> LABEL=The\040Volume\040Name\040Is\040This none    msdos ro
> ```

(Which makes me wonder when Apple gave up on deprecating `/etc/fstab`.)